# Parâmetro como array(cakephp)

Tags: array, cakephp

Estou passando essa um array contendo dados de um formulário, para uma função, mas no php acusa esse erro. **Cannot use string offset as an array.**

```
public function add($galeria_id) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        foreach ($this->request->data['Foto'] as $dados){
            $this->criarfoto($galeria_id, $dados);
        }
    }
    $this->render('form');
}

private function criarfoto($galeria_id, $file){
    $extension = pathinfo($file['imagem']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $allowExt = array(
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png',
        'gif',
    );
    if(!in_array($extension, $allowExt)){
        return false;
    }
    $fotos_galeria = array(
        'galeria_id' => $galeria_id,
        'hot' => $file['hot'],
        'titulo' => $file['titulo'],
        'descricao' => $file['descricao'],
        'extension' => $extension,
    );
    $this->Foto->create();
    if ($this->Foto->save($fotos_galeria)){
        //continuação..
```

Pelo jeito, ele não está setando os indices dos outros campos, o problema era esse, quando eu dou um `print_r` em `$file`ele me retorna uma estrutura assim:

```
 Galeria de testesmichelakasdkasdasdArray

[name] => compre34.jpg
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => /tmp/php8f7w6H
[error] => 0
[size] => 25799
```

e o certo teria que ser uma estrutura assim:

```
  Array

[titulo] => Galeria de testes,
[descricao] => michelakasdkasdasd,
[name] => compre34.jpg
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => /tmp/php8f7w6H
[error] => 0
[size] => 25799
```

Comment: Tem mais detalhes deste erro? Qual arquivo, a linha do erro, o log completo que o *CakePHP* exibe na tela?

Comment: Error: Cannot use string offset as an array
File: /var/www/intercambioglobal.com.br/app/Plugin/Galeria/Controller/FotosController.php


linha 34:
`$extension = pathinfo($file['imagem']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: A questão, é que, não consigo passar um array, como parâmetro de uma função, é possível fazer isso?

Comment: Você garantiu que `$file['imagem']['name']` é realmente uma *string*? Tente colocar em um [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) antes para ter certeza.

Comment: retorno do meu vardump:`string(8) "cape.jpg" `

Comment: É provável que o erro não esteja nesta função então. Ao salvar, experimente assim: `$this->Foto->save(array('Foto' => $fotos_galeria))`.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha pergunta novamente.

Comment: Resolvido, quando eu passava o `$this->request->data['Foto']`, ele estava passando todos os argumento direto, e como ele só tem um form, passei somente o `$this->request->data`, e aí, ele me passou todos indices com seus valores.